# CUDA Optimization

Tags: c++, cuda

I developed Pincushion Distortion using CUDA to support real time - more than 40 fps for 3680*2456 Image Sequences.

But it takes 130ms if I use CUDA   -   nVIDIA GeForce GT 610, 2GB DDR3.

But it takes only 60ms if I use CPU and OpenMP  -  Core i7 3.4GHz, QuadCore.

Please tell me what to do to speed up.
Thanks.

Full source can be downloaded here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9SEJgsu0G6QX2FpMnRja0o5STA/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9SEJgsu0G6QOGNPMmVQLWpSb2c/view?usp=sharing

The codes are as follows.

```
__global__
void undistort(int N, float k, int width, int height, int depth, int pitch, float R, float L, unsigned char* in_bits, unsigned char* out_bits)
{
    // Get the Index of the Array from GPU Grid/Block/Thread Index and Dimension.
    int i, j;
    i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // If Out of Array
    if (i >= height || j >= width)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Calculating Undistortion Equation.
    // In CPU, We used Fast Approximation equations of atan and sqrt - It makes 2 times faster.
    // But In GPU, No need to use Approximation Functions as it is faster.

    int cx = width  * 0.5;
    int cy = height * 0.5;

    int xt = j - cx;
    int yt = i - cy;

    float distance = sqrt((float)(xt*xt + yt*yt));
    float r = distance*k / R;

    float theta = 1;
    if (r == 0)
        theta = 1;
    else
        theta = atan(r)/r;

    theta = theta*L;

    float tx = theta*xt + cx;
    float ty = theta*yt + cy;

    // When we correct the frame, its size will be greater than Original.
    // So We should Crop it.
    if (tx < 0)
        tx = 0;
    if (tx >= width)
        tx = width - 1;
    if (ty < 0)
        ty = 0;
    if (ty >= height)
        ty = height - 1;

    // Output the Result.
    int ux = (int)(tx);
    int uy = (int)(ty);

    tx = tx - ux;
    ty = ty - uy;

    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)out_bits + i*pitch + j*depth;
    unsigned char *q00 = (unsigned char*)in_bits + uy*pitch + ux*depth;
    unsigned char *q01 = q00 + depth;
    unsigned char *q10 = q00 + pitch;
    unsigned char *q11 = q10 + depth;

    unsigned char newVal[4] = {0};
    for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
    {
        newVal[k] = (q00[k]*(1-tx)*(1-ty) + q01[k]*tx*(1-ty) + q10[k]*(1-tx)*ty + q11[k]*tx*ty);
        memcpy(p + k, &newVal[k], 1);
    }

}

void wideframe_correction(char* bits, int width, int height, int depth)
{
    // Find the device.
    // Initialize the nVIDIA Device.
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, 0);

    // This works for Calculating GPU Time.
    cudaProfilerStart();

    // This works for Measuring Total Time
    long int dwTime = clock();

    // Setting Distortion Parameters
    // Note that Multiplying 0.5 works faster than divide into 2.
    int cx = (int)(width * 0.5);
    int cy = (int)(height * 0.5);
    float k = -0.73f;
    float R = sqrt((float)(cx*cx + cy*cy));

    // Set the Radius of the Result.
    float L = (float)(width<height ? width:height);
    L = L/2.0f;
    L = L/R;
    L = L*L*L*0.3333f;
    L = 1.0f/(1-L);

    // Create the GPU Memory Pointers.
    unsigned char* d_img_in = NULL;
    unsigned char* d_img_out = NULL;

    // Allocate the GPU Memory2D with pitch for fast performance.
    size_t pitch;
    cudaMallocPitch( (void**) &d_img_in, &pitch, width*depth, height );
    cudaMallocPitch( (void**) &d_img_out, &pitch, width*depth, height );
    _tprintf(_T("\nPitch : %d\n"), pitch);

    // Copy RAM data to VRAM.
    cudaMemcpy2D( d_img_in, pitch, 
            bits, width*depth, width*depth, height, 
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy2D( d_img_out, pitch, 
            bits, width*depth, width*depth, height, 
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    // Create Variables for Timing
    cudaEvent_t startEvent, stopEvent;
    cudaError_t err = cudaEventCreate(&startEvent, 0);
    assert( err == cudaSuccess );
    err = cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent, 0);
    assert( err == cudaSuccess );

    // Execution of the version using global memory
    float elapsedTime;
    cudaEventRecord(startEvent);

    // Process image
    dim3 dGrid(width / BLOCK_WIDTH + 1, height / BLOCK_HEIGHT + 1);
    dim3 dBlock(BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_HEIGHT);

    undistort<<< dGrid, dBlock >>> (width*height, k,  width, height, depth, pitch, R, L, d_img_in, d_img_out);

    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaEventRecord(stopEvent);
    cudaEventSynchronize( stopEvent );

    // Estimate the GPU Time.
    cudaEventElapsedTime( &elapsedTime, startEvent, stopEvent);

    // Calculate the Total Time.
    dwTime = clock() - dwTime;

    // Save Image data from VRAM to RAM
    cudaMemcpy2D( bits, width*depth, 
        d_img_out, pitch, width*depth, height,
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    _tprintf(_T("GPU Processing Time(ms) : %d\n"), (int)elapsedTime);
    _tprintf(_T("VRAM Memory Read/Write Time(ms) : %d\n"), dwTime - (int)elapsedTime);
    _tprintf(_T("Total Time(ms) : %d\n"), dwTime );

    // Free GPU Memory
    cudaFree(d_img_in);
    cudaFree(d_img_out);
    cudaProfilerStop();
    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

Comment: `Multiplying 0.5 works faster than divide into 2.` No it doesn't; this requires both an int to float and float to int conversion, relatively expensive operations. And instead of `memcpy(p + k, &newVal[k], 1);`, why not just do `p[k] = newVal[k];`?

Comment: As a follow-on, I would make `cx`, `cy`, `xt`, and `yt` all `float` to minimise unnecessary type conversions. Furthermore, [newer versions of OpenMP support the GPU](https://parallel-computing.pro/index.php/9-cuda/43-openmp-4-0-on-nvidia-cuda-gpus), which might explain why the compiler is beating your hand-rolled kernel.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile. The CUDA profiler is very good and will tell you much more than any of us can just by looking at your code. That being said, your read/store loop at the end seems to be completely uncoalesced and GPUs are very unforgiving when it comes to scattered accesses. (And also terrible load/store efficiency as you seem to be manipulating `char` by `char` at a time).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow - if you have a *specific* question about a performance optimization, [SO] is the right place to ask an optimization focused question. If you question is "Please tell me what to do to make my code fast", you have come to the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One does not simply optimize the code just by looking to the source. First of all, you should use Nvidia Profiler https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler and see, which part of your code on GPU is the one taking too much time. You might wish to write a UnitTest first however, just to be sure that only the investigated part of your project is tested.

Additionally, you can use CallGrind http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html to test your CPU code performance.

In general, this is not very surprising that your GPU "optimized" code is slower then "not optimized" one. CUDA cores are usually several times slower than CPU and you have to actually introduce a lot of parallelism to notice a significant speed-up.

EDIT, response to your comment:

As a unit testing framework I strongly recommend GoogleTest. [Here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md) you can learn how to use it. Apart from its obvious functionalities (code testing) it allows you to run only specific methods from your class interfaces for performance analysis.

In general, Nvidia profiler is just a tool that runs your code and tells you how much time each of your kernel consume. Please look to their [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#axzz3yRSJGcyj).

By "lot of parallelism" I meant: on your processor you can run 8 x 3.4GHz threads, your GPU has one SM (streaming multiprocessor) with 810MHz clock, lets say 1024 threads per SM (I do not have exact data, but you can run deviceQuery Nvidia script to know the exact parameters), therefore if your GPU code can run (3.4*8)/0.81 = 33 computations in parallel, you will achieve exactly nothing. Execution time of your CPU and GPU code will be the same (neglecting L-cache GPU memory copying, which is expensive). Conclusion: your GPU code should be able to compute at least ~ 40 operations in parallel to introduce any speed-up. On the other hand, lets say that you are able to fully use your GPU potential and you can keep all 1024 on your SM busy all the time. In that case your code will run only (0.81*1024)/(8*3.4) = 30 times faster (approximately, remember that we neglect GPU L-cache operations), which is impossible in most cases, because usually you are not able to parallelize your serial code with such efficiency.

Wish you good luck with your research!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In fact, I've no idea about UnitTest or nVidia-Profiler.
Would you please tell me in details about them and about what you mean "A lot of parallelism"?

Comment: As a unit testing framework I strongly recommend GoogleTest. [Here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md) you can learn how to use it. Apart from its obvious functionalities (code testing) it allows you to run only specific methods from your class interfaces for performance analysis.

Answer (score 2):

i've not read the source code, but there is some things you can't pass through.

your GPU has nearly same performance as your CPU:

Adapt the follwing informations with your real GPU/CPU model.

```
Specification | GPU          | CPU
----------------------------------------
Bandwith      | 14,4 GB/sec  | 25.6 GB/s
Flops         | 155 (FMA)    |  135
```

we can conclude that for memory bounded kernels your GPU will never be faster than your CPU.

GPU informations found here : 
http://www.nvidia.fr/object/geforce-gt-610-fr.html#pdpContent=2

CPU informations found here : http://ark.intel.com/products/75123/Intel-Core-i7-4770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?q=Intel%20Core%20i7%204770K

and here http://www.ocaholic.ch/modules/smartsection/item.php?page=6&itemid=1005

Comment: One could make that statement even stronger: Since the code in question is memory bound, and the GPU used offers significantly less memory bandwidth than the CPU, we would expect the code to run *slower* on the GPU. In fact the ratio of the computation time is nearly inverse the proportion of respective memory bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put nvprof to good use, it's a great tool.

What I could see from your code...
1. Consider using linear thread blocks instead of flat blocks, it could save up some integer operations.
2. Manual correction of image borders and/or thread indices leads to massive divergence and/or impacts coalescing. Consider using texture fetches and/or pre-padding data.
3. memcpy single value from inside the kernel is generally a bad idea.
4. Try to minimize type conversions.